# How do you pipe "echo" into "openssl"?

Tags: openssl

I am simply trying to submit the "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0" request to SSL-enabled web servers; however, when running this, I am just simply getting "DONE" At the end of the connection.

Here's the exact command that I'm using:

```
echo -e "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect site.com:443
```

Any suggestions? I'm sure I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: Note that `echo -e "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"` sends a (third) newline at the end. To suppress it use `echo -ne "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"`. And you can use `openssl s_client ... -ign_eof -pause` at the right side.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

the problem is discussed in this thread (the linked email has the only simple answer, which i'll repeat below): http://www.mail-archive.com/openssl-users@openssl.org/msg02937.html

```
(echo "GET /"; sleep 10) | openssl s_client -connect news.ycombinator.com:443
```

the problem being that s_client shuts down as soon as stdin closes.  so your code works fine, but s_client is exiting after receiving the OPTIONS and before receiving the server response.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was looking for. I couldn't find the resource I located a few weeks back, and here we go. Thanks :).

Not sure how to mark your answer as correct though :\

Comment: The mailing list conversation was from 1999; that's probably why the option to change the behavior was added in the next release.

Comment: What worked for me was adding `-ign_eof` to the `openssl s_client` command. (The `sleep` and parentheses didn't do the trick, even though the response should have arrived in less than a second.)

Comment: I would like to execute the openssl s_client -connect fiestyduck.com:443 and then want to use GET / HTTP/1.1 in python ? how can i request in a single command using sub_process .  currently popen = subprocess.Popen("(echo ' "GET /" '; sleep 5) | C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\openssl.exe s_client -connect news.ycombinator.com:443"),stdin=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) which is throwing an syntax error

Answer (score 85):

There's an `-ign_eof` option which does exactly what you want without any hacks. It's been in the codebase since 2000 (0.9.5a), apparently.

The option suppresses the special interpretation of Q and R, and ignores an EOF on stdin. Instead, it waits for a connection close.

Comment: This is definitely the superior answer.

Answer (score 18):

Late answer...

seems if you add a 'cat' to your subshell it works.

```
(echo -ne "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: google.com\r\n\r\n" ; cat ) | openssl s_client -connect google.com:443
```

That 'cat' hangs around, and you can actually then continue interacting with s_client manually. I have only done a single test here, but I need this same ability to pipe in http headesr/bodies from command line to an ssl server.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` this worked for me:

```
openssl s_client -ign_eof -crlf -connect server:port < <(echo "COMMAND1"; sleep 2; echo "COMMAND2";)
```

Example login to IMAP, wait 2 sec and logout:

```
username="<username@web.de>"
password="<password>"
openssl s_client -ign_eof -crlf -connect imap.web.de:993 < <(echo "a001 LOGIN $username $password"; sleep 2; echo "a002 LOGOUT";)

CONNECTED(00000006)
depth=2 C = DE, O = T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, OU = T-Systems Trust Center, CN = T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2
verify return:1
depth=1 C = DE, O = Deutsche Telekom Security GmbH, CN = Telekom Security ServerID OV Class 2 CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, O = 1&1 Mail & Media GmbH, ST = Rheinland-Pfalz, L = Montabaur, CN = smtp.web.de
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = DE, O = 1&1 Mail & Media GmbH, ST = Rheinland-Pfalz, L = Montabaur, CN = smtp.web.de
   i:C = DE, O = Deutsche Telekom Security GmbH, CN = Telekom Security ServerID OV Class 2 CA
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 2048 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Mar 28 08:54:56 2023 GMT; NotAfter: Apr  1 23:59:59 2024 GMT
 1 s:C = DE, O = Deutsche Telekom Security GmbH, CN = Telekom Security ServerID OV Class 2 CA
   i:C = DE, O = T-Systems Enterprise Services GmbH, OU = T-Systems Trust Center, CN = T-TeleSec GlobalRoot Class 2
   a:PKEY: rsaEncryption, 3072 (bit); sigalg: RSA-SHA256
   v:NotBefore: Aug  2 09:16:44 2022 GMT; NotAfter: Aug  2 23:59:59 2027 GMT
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=C = DE, O = 1&1 Mail & Media GmbH, ST = Rheinland-Pfalz, L = Montabaur, CN = smtp.web.de
issuer=C = DE, O = Deutsche Telekom Security GmbH, CN = Telekom Security ServerID OV Class 2 CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA-PSS
Server Temp Key: X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4113 bytes and written 393 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
This TLS version forbids renegotiation.
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN ENABLE ID IDLE LIST-EXTENDED LIST-STATUS LITERAL- MOVE NAMESPACE QUOTA SASL-IR SORT SPECIAL-USE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT UIDPLUS UNSELECT WITHIN AUTH=LOGIN AUTH=PLAIN] IMAP server ready H miweb083 27.4 IMAP-...
a001 OK LOGIN completed
* BYE Server logging out
a002 OK LOGOUT completed
closed
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for both `HTTP/1.0` and `HTTP/1.1` for sites with [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) enabled:

```
site="site.com"
echo -ne "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: $site\r\n\r\n" | \
timeout 5 openssl s_client -ign_eof -servername $site -connect $site:443
```