# How do I invoke actions in my Bash script after something like openssl is ran?

Tags: bash

`openssl` takes over the input into its own interactive environment from what I can tell.

I want to try something like this:

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -crlf -ign_eof
```

As the first line in my Bash script, then after that send some SMTP commands like `HELO localhost`. But if I put it right after that line in my `script.sh` file, and run it with `sh`, the second line never gets sent.

How do I accomplish something like this in a Bash script?

Comment: You need to pipe the commands into the openssl client.  Like this: (echo "GET /"; sleep 10) | openssl s_client -connect news.ycombinator.com:443

Taken from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147280/how-do-you-pipe-echo-into-openssl

Comment: @McKracken I think it would be better to post your comment as an answer since it looks like it's the correct solution. Then Doug can accept your answer -- assuming it works for him.