# How can I send an HTTPS request from a file?

Tags: shell, openssl

Let's assume I have a file request.txt that looks like:

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Some_header: value

text=blah
```

I tried:

```
cat request.txt | openssl -s_client -connect server.com:443
```

Unfortunately it didn't work and I need to manually copy & paste the file contents. How can I do it within a script?

Comment: Seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147280/how-do-you-pipe-echo-into-openssl

Answer (score 0):

`cat` is not ideally suited to download remote files, it's best used for files local to the file system running the script. To download a remote file you have other commands that you can use which handle this better.

If your environment has `wget` installed you can download the file by URL. Here is a link for some [examples on how it's used](http://www.labnol.org/software/wget-command-examples/28750/). That would look like:

```
wget https://server.com/request.txt
```

If your environment has `curl` installed you can download the file by URL. Here is a link for some [examples on how it's used](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html). That would look like:

```
curl -O  https://server.com/request.txt
```

Please note that if you want to store the response in a variable for further modification you can do this as well with a bit more work.

Also worth noting is that if you *really* must use `cat` to download a remote file it's possible, but it may require `ssh` to be used and I'm not a fan of using that method as it requires access to a file via `ssh` where it's already publicly available over HTTP/S. There isn't a practical reason I can think of to go about it this way, but for the sake of completion I wanted to mention that it *could* be done but probably shouldn't.

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't clarify enough. I have prepared some special request with special headers and special binary data I want to SEND to server. The whole request is in reqiest.txt I have on my computer and now I want tha to be transferred and sent. So you think it's not very possible to do it via openssl and I have to somehow push it throguh curl?

Comment: Would you mind updating your question with the info you just provided? Also any other info would be good to know your intent. I wasn't clear from what's there but it seems like from what you've just written that you want to process a local text file in order to send data to a remote server. Is that right?

Comment: I have a request I want to send and the request is in the file. The question says exactly that.