# cat request.txt | openssl s_client -connect www.baidu.com:433 return nothing of HTTP

Tags: openssl

I am testing my request to some https servers. here is my request.txt.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host www.baidu.com
(BLANK LINE HERE)
```

but when I type command

```
cat request.txt | openssl s_client -connect www.baidu.com:433
```

it prints something about TLS handshake without any about http response.
However, if I `openssl s_client -connect www.baidu.com:433`, and then type that request, it works.

So, how to pass a request to openssl by pipe?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How do you pipe “echo” into “openssl”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19147280). HTTP uses `\r\n`, not Linux `\n` or OS X `\r`. You might also use TLS1 and Server Name Indication (SNI) with `openssl s_client -connect www.baidu.com:433 -tls1 -servername www.baidu.com`.

Comment: Thanks to @jww. It's sovled perfectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pipe "echo" into "openssl"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19147280/how-do-you-pipe-echo-into-openssl)