# Openssl Open Session - Special ASCII Characters

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I have successfully connected to my sever using the openssl s_client -connect command. Now I want to send the following value 0x2003 during the session but I don't find the way to send it as a hex. I was also considering to translated to ASCII but the 03 is the 'End of Text' character but I don't know how to type it. Any help would be more than welcome!

The echo command does work fine, although I have to say that for windows you will have to use the printf instead of echo (Need to install Cygwing).

What if I want to send another command in the same session? With the command below the session is closed once the command is sent. So I would like to keep the session open and send hex values whenever I need. Is there a way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The HTTP protocol (including the HTTPS variant) does not allow control characters, or any characters other than ASCII printable (and not always all of those) plus CR LF, in headers; whether they are allowed in bodies varies depending on content-type. Moreover for values more than 8 bits there are many different ways of expressing them in bytes, not only the obvious one of high-byte-first (aka big-endian, or network-endian because it is used in many lower-level Internet protocols). Can you be more specific about what you are doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux you can use the pipe as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19148270/7748072). Luckily the `echo` command allows the translation you're thinking about by using `\x03`

For example try this to send your ASCII 03 char in the URL and in the cookie value :

```
(echo -e 'GET /foo\x03bar HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com\r\nCookie:cookie foo\x03bar\r\n\r\n' ; sleep 5) | openssl s_client -servername stackoverflow.com -connect stackoverflow.com:443
```

Comment: Some versions of `echo` support `-e` but some don't. On all 'Unixy' (POSIX-conforming) systems `printf` supports backslash escapes including `\x`, but OpenSSL runs on quite a few non-POSIX systems. In any case, putting such a character in a URL, or otherwise in an HTTP header (like a cookie), violates the applicable specifications -- and stack rejects with 400, as it should.

Comment: Thanks once more @dave_thompson_085 . Violating the specifications is often a good way to check if an implementation is good, or if we shouldn't trust it. That's true that my example should lead to a 400 status.